# Многопоточность.threading.Timer, daemon, Как устроено?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, многопоточность

Суть в чём. Работаю на Джанге. Точно не знаю, но догадываюсь, что есть какой-то основной поток, который происходит от процесса запущенного сервером, который обрабатывает запрос пользователя, и затем сразу прекращает свою работу.

В этом потоке нужно запустить ещё один поток, который должен отработать простейшую функцию(например print), через некоторое время, например через минуту.

Я так понял, что лучший выбор для меня Timer в модуле threading.

Но, если поток не является daemon, то тогда и родительский поток будет висеть минуту вместе с дочерним, так-как не сможет прекратить свою работу, и будет кушать ресурсы? Я правильно понимаю?
То есть мне нужно устанавливать свойство daemon = True?

Чем, программно и по свойствам, отличается обычный поток от daemon? Какие данные он хранит? Тоже хотелось бы узнать. В каких случаях следует использовать каждый из типов?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

При завершении работы `__main__` потока

все [`daemon`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/threading.html#thread-objects) потоки будут принудительно завершены

все `не daemon` потоки продолжат свою работу

```
import threading, sys

def printer():
    print('threading print')

def fn():
    print('start fn')
    threading.Timer(1, printer).start()
    print('stop fn')
```

`daemon=False`

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.exit(threading.Thread(target=fn, daemon=False).start())
    # главный поток должен бы 'завершится' тут
    # но тк fn-поток не Daemon, главный будет ждать завершения выполнения fn()
```

`out:`

```
start fn
stop fn
threading print
```

`daemon=True`

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.exit(threading.Thread(target=fn, daemon=True).start())
    # главный поток завершится тут.
    # но тк fn-поток Daemon, выполнение fn() прервется
```

`out:`

```
start fn
```

из threading.py

```
@property
def daemon(self):
    """A boolean value indicating whether this thread is a daemon thread.

    This must be set before start() is called, otherwise RuntimeError is
    raised. Its initial value is inherited from the creating thread; the
    main thread is not a daemon thread and therefore all threads created in
    the main thread default to daemon = False.

    The entire Python program exits when no alive non-daemon threads are
    left.

    """
```

Comment: Три раза прочитал, так и не понял, на какой вопрос это ответ.

Comment: На тот, что в вашем примере 3 потока: Есть __main__ поток [1] . Есть поток-родитель [2](который обрабатывает запрос пользователя, и затем сразу прекращает свою работу). Есть daemon print-поток [3]. Поток [3] не будет висеть минуту вместе с потоком-[2] тк  daemon определяет только поведение потока [3], после завершения работы потока [1], и поток [2] может завершить выполнение, до начала print из потока [3]

Comment: Вы хорошо всё расписали. Спасибо большое за уделённое время. Но в вашем ответе нет ответа на вопрос.

Comment: Ну и под номером [1] всё-таки процесс, а не поток.

Comment: Отдал награду. Видимо в вопросе никто не разбирается.

Answer (score 5):

> Точно не знаю, но догадываюсь, что есть какой-то основной поток,
>   который происходит от процесса запущенного сервером, который
>   обрабатывает запрос пользователя, и затем сразу прекращает свою
>   работу.

Нет, скрипты django-проекта загружаются [WSGI](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/WSGI)-сервером в память при старте и остаются там до окончания его работы. Исключая нюансы, вроде перезапуска процессов WSGI-сервера при наступлении некоторых событий.

WSGI-сервер при поступлении http-запросов вызывает [WSGIHandler](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py#L130), который в свою очередь вызывает соответствующие *представления*, будь то функция или метод [CBV](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/class-based-views/). Представление должно как можно быстрее дать ответ на запрос и завершить работу. Поэтому любые длительные задачи надо перекладывать на фоновые сервисы.

> Я так понял, что лучший выбор для меня Timer в модуле threading.

Нет, лучший выбор для вас - это [Celery](http://www.celeryproject.org/).

Django не просто непотокобезопасный, он специально спроектирован однозадачным. Любые попытки использовать в нём потоки или асинхронность - это путь к неизбежным и трудноуловимым ошибкам.

А Celery - это стандарт де-факто для фоновых и периодических задач в django-разработке. Имеющиеся альтернативы в виде uWSGI Spooler или Huey могут похвастаться только большей простотой настройки, но имеют существенно меньше возможностей и крошечные сообщества.